# Vertical roller menu

Tags: jquery, css

HI guys does any of you know how/where can i find a vertical roller menu similar like these

[image: menu with more categories]

[image]

it would be great if anyone can show me probably jquery based roller menu. I think it limits number of categories to be displayed.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the following link..

[www.freedownloadmanager.org/.../jquery-vertical-roller-menu](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/.../jquery-vertical-roller-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I looked around for you and the closest thing I could find was this: 
http://plugins.righthere.com/downloadable-content/sws-sliding-tabs-extra/
Scroll down a bit and you'll see it. This IS a free Wordpress plugin, but you can always DL it and analyze it.

If you wanted to go with something a bit different, you could customize something like this:
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/188/jQuery-Super-Cool-Vertical-Scroll-Menu
Although imo there are a limited number of cases where that would actually be very usable.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm... maybe it isn't free! Looks like an add-on to a paid plugin.
As an alternative, you could just use a vertical slider that lets you slide between divs, and have vertical tabs in each div.